# Trouble with multiple relationships? (Relationships field)

Tags: relationships, related-entries

I have a Relationships field called "relate_entries".
This field is set to relate to just one channel. I no problem calling the title when it is not looping by setting things up like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="kalender" 
    sort="asc" 
    show_future_entries="yes" 
    show_expired="no" 
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|trackbacks"}

{relate_entries:title}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But if I try to output multiple related entries it doesnt work.

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="kalender" 
    sort="asc" 
    show_future_entries="yes" 
    show_expired="no"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|trackbacks"}

    {relate_entries}
        {relate_entries:title}
    {/relate_entries} 

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Thanks for any help.

EE 6.0.2

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean - could you provide examples of what happens?

Comment: Nothing happens. Nothing is outputted. I though my description was pretty well explained. Did you read all of my post?

Comment: What do you see if you replace `:title` with `:entry_ids` in the two examples?

Comment: If I use `:entry_ids` alone it outputs the entries ids but if I use it between the relationships tags it doesn´t output anything. Like this: `{relate_entries}{relate_entries:entry_ids}
    {/relate_entries}`

Comment: Interesting - I guess `{entry_ids}` doesn't like being in a loop. If you replace `{entry_ids}` with `{entry_id}` in the looping example, what do you get?  I've tried this on an EE6.0.2 test system here and the relationship tags work correctly - suspect either something weird on your system, or a typo somewhere.

Comment: `{entry_id}` doesnt output anything. Its really strange as Ive set up Relationships of several other site with no problem. Ive deactivated all the addons Im using except Low Events so I wonder if this is the culprit? Waiting to get an updated version as I dont want to uninstall it.

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe it is the add-on.  You could try disabling it in `developer/utilities/manage extensions` and see if issue goes away.  But generally Low's stuff is rock-solid, so don't think it will be that.

Comment: It not listed here. The version I have is not tested on EE 6 so Ill install the newest version and see if that helps. If not I think Ill have to reinstall EE which is a bit of a bind but... Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Are you using custom statuses in your channel? If so you need you might need to account for that, showing future entries as well:


    `{relate_entries status="not closed" show_future_entries="yes"}{relate_entries:title}{/relate_entries}`

Comment: Hi, Thanks you. That was exactly the problem. I wasn´t using `show_future_entries="yes"`. This is not very well documented in the manual.